# Can PloneFormGen's mailer adapter include hidden / server-side-only fields?

Tags: plone, ploneformgen

I'm using PloneFormGen's mailer adapter and noticed it omits hidden or server-side-only fields from the e-mail. How do I save those fields?

Answer (score 1):

Server-side-only fields are excluded from the mailer's body template by this code: https://github.com/smcmahon/Products.PloneFormGen/blob/master/Products/PloneFormGen/content/formMailerAdapter.py#L725

One way to include those values in the e-mail is to include them in the mailer template as `<div tal:content="python:request.form.get('field-name')">field value</div>`. If you only need those values in the mailer then it might be just as practical to produce them in the template without going through the form.